rule failed to match in python?
I am using the playground the following pattern fails to match the code
id: match-specific-function
language: python
rule:
  kind: function_definition
  inside:
    kind: class_definition
    regex: account.account

failed to match any in the following python code
from bisect import bisect_left
from collections import defaultdict
import contextlib
import itertools
import re
import json

from odoo import api, fields, models, _, Command
from odoo.osv import expression
from odoo.exceptions import UserError, ValidationError, RedirectWarning
from odoo.tools import SQL, Query


ACCOUNT_REGEX = re.compile(r'(?:(\S*\d+\S*))?(.*)')
ACCOUNT_CODE_REGEX = re.compile(r'^[A-Za-z0-9.]+$')
ACCOUNT_CODE_NUMBER_REGEX = re.compile(r'(.*?)(\d*)(\D*?)$')

def _the_best(self):
    pass


class AccountAccount(models.Model):
    _name = "account.account"
    _inherit = ['mail.thread']
    _description = "Account"
    _order = "code, placeholder_code"
    _check_company_auto = True
    _check_company_domain = models.check_companies_domain_parent_of

    name = fields.Char(string="Account Name", required=True, index='trigram', tracking=True, translate=True)
    currency_id = fields.Many2one('res.currency', string='Account Currency', tracking=True,
        help="Forces all journal items in this account to have a specific currency (i.e. bank journals). If no currency is set, entries can use any currency.")
    
    def _the_best(self):
        pass

class AccountAccount(models.Model):
    _name = "sale.order"
    _inherit = ['mail.thread']
    _description = "Account"
    _order = "code, placeholder_code"
    _check_company_auto = True
    _check_company_domain = models.check_companies_domain_parent_of

    def _the_best(self):
        pass

class AccountAccount(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'account.account'
    
    def _the_best(self):
        pass
    
    def _the_best2(self):
        pass

what I would like to match is the method named def the_best inside class which has a definition of _name = 'account.account' or _inherit = 'account.account', could you help me, please?
so that the result to match only
def _the_best(self):
    pass

in classes which has definition _name = 'account.account' or _inherit = 'account.account'

after multiple tests I was able to do it using the following:
id: match-specific-function
language: python
rule:
  kind: function_definition
  regex: def _the_best
  inside:
    kind: block
    has:
      regex: (_name|_inherit) = ('|")account.account('|")

but I was expecting to use kind: class_definition instead of kind: block
